# Is it Possible to Download Excel File from Tabulator Filling a Template?

Tags: javascript, excel, tabulator

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm currently working with Tabulator, a fantastic grid library for interactive tables, and I've encountered a challenge that I'm hoping to get some insights on.

I'm aware that Tabulator allows for the export of table data to various formats, including Excel. However, my requirement is a bit more specific. I need to download table data into an Excel file, but instead of exporting it as a standard Excel file, I want to fill a pre-defined Excel template with this data. Essentially, the data from Tabulator should populate specific cells or ranges in an already formatted Excel template.

Here's a brief outline of what I'm trying to achieve:

- Pre-Existing Excel Template: I have an Excel template with specific
  formatting, formulas, and predefined headers.
- Tabulator Table Data: My web application generates dynamic data
  displayed in a Tabulator table.
- Desired Outcome: On triggering an export action, the data from the
  Tabulator table should be exported into the Excel template,
  populating specific areas of the template while preserving the
  original formatting and formulas.

I'm not sure if this functionality is natively supported in Tabulator or if there are known workarounds or plugins that can achieve this. My main questions are:

- Is it possible to directly export Tabulator data into a pre-formatted Excel template?
- If direct export is not possible, would be possible to export the data to a separate sheet where the cell values are linked to the pre-formatted Excel sheet?
- If both of this solution are not available, what would be the best approach to achieve this functionality?

Any guidance, advice, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to creative solutions or alternative approaches if direct export to a template is not feasible.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!